# Check if the drive is removable from C program? (Windows)

Tags: c, windows

I have a drive called "E". How do I check if it is removable from my c program?

Comment: @bolt19 I didn't have any idea....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  googling the exact title of the question gets your more or less instantaneously to the Microsoft documentation dealing with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code for achieving what you want:

```
#include <FileAPI.h>
//
//
if(GetDriveType("E:\\") == DRIVE_REMOVABLE)
{
    // Above mentioned drive is a removable drive
}
```

Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks `Satya Pawan`!
This works!